# how can I make a function that runs every 15 minutes?

Tags: function, discord.js

I want to do a function that runs every **15 minutes** and that adds an item, always every 15 minutes, *discord.js*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a function at a set interval, you have two options: `setInterval()` and `cron` jobs.

---

[**`setInterval()`**](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args)

```js
let timer = setInterval(function() {
  // code
  console.log('done');
}, 1000*60*15); // time is in milliseconds. 1000 ms * 60 sec * 15 min
```

To stop the timer, use `clearInterval(timer)`.

---

[**Cron Jobs**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

```js
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
let job = new CronJob('*/15 * * * *', function() { // '*/15' = every 15
  // code
}, console.log('done'), true, null, null, true);
```

To stop the job, use `job.stop()`. You can also use `job.start()` to start it manually, but with the code above, the job is set to start as soon as it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Do stuff..."); }, 900000);
```